# VSCode Terminal creates indent after using tab to auto complete commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I am using the VSCode terminal for most of my dev work and I am ssh'ed into a remote server but whenever I use the autocomplete hotkey (TAB) the terminal interface indents the text and treats the text field as if the line begins at a tabulated spot (basically I can't delete the tab character). I am unsure if this is a result of the VSCode Terminal settings or my zsh setup.

For example:

[image: Terminal before using tab]

[image: Terminal after using tab]

My PS1 is:

`PS1='${txtpur}$(ps1_context)${bldgrn}%n${bldwht}@${bldylw}%m ${bldcyn}%1d${NEWLINE}${txtrst}'`

The color variables are from https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt.

I have tried messing with PS1 as well as looking through the Terminal settings on VSCode but I am not finding anything that may pertain to this.